# Displacement doesn't work

Tags: displacement, bump

It's frustrating that every time I try to mark a logo with some bump using displacement, displacement just doesn't work!

here's some screenshot of the problem and blender file.
[image]

1. the texture just with the displacement
   [image]
2. result
   [image]
   [image]
3. texture setting (displacement and bump turn on)
   [image]
4. Scene setting
   [image]
5. PNG I use
   [image]
6. edit mode with some subdivide on top surface
   [image]
7. logo arrangement (on the center of the top surface)
   [image]

Could someone help me with this problem?
I felt so frustrated cause it happen all the time!

Comment: could you please pack the image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: OK! No problem!

Comment: The packed file is uploaded! @moonboots

Answer (score 0):

The *Displacement* node needs topology to displace, so either subdivide your object or give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, also put the *Midlevel* value at 1:

[image]

Comment: Great! Now it works! Thank you so much! @moonboots